# Windows Forms - Problem adding row when pressing enter

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, algorithm

What I'm trying to do is that when i press enter in an active cell, it should add a new row but instead i had to press 2 times and don't know how to focus it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2N3Y.jpg

```
private void dgv_lis_KexDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
   {
    dgv_lis.Rows.Add();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a new Row without parameter.

You must define the contents, see example:

```
//create DataTable
DataTable Your_DT = new DataTable();
Your_DT.Columns.Add("first_Column", typeof(string));
Your_DT.Columns.Add("second_Column", typeof(string));

//add new row
DataRow newRow = Your_DT.NewRow();
newRow["first_Column"] = "test";
newRow["second_Column"] = "test2";
Your_DT.Rows.Add(newRow);

//link DataTable to datagridview
dataGridView1.DataSource = Your_DT;
```

Comment: To be more clear, i need to add a new row with only one press.

Comment: Where is your focus? One press in a TextBox? Do you want to add an empty line in Datagridview?